# Read csv data to matlab

Tags: matlab, csv, octave

i have issues parsing a csv file:

```
Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume,Adj Close
2014-08-22,16.08,16.19,15.80,16.00,139800,16.00
2014-08-21,16.16,16.33,16.00,16.10,128500,16.10
2014-08-20,16.00,16.28,15.78,16.15,271200,16.15
2014-08-19,16.20,16.27,15.96,16.04,379600,16.04
2014-08-18,16.87,16.87,16.10,16.16,259200,16.16
2014-08-15,16.54,16.55,16.21,16.38,190900,16.38
```

my current code looks like that:

```
hist_data_f = fopen(hist_path)
fgets(hist_data_f);
hist_data = textscan(hist_data_f, '%s,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d')
```

the current result is this:

```
hist_data =
{
  [1,1] =
  {
    [1,1] = 2014-08-22,16.08,16.19,15.80,16.00,139800,16.00
    [2,1] = 2014-08-21
    [3,1] = ,
    [4,1] = 16.20
    [5,1] = ,
    [6,1] = 16.55
    [7,1] = ,
    [8,1] = 16.41
    [9,1] = ,
    [10,1] = 16.53
    [11,1] = ,
    [12,1] = 327700,16.13
    [13,1] = 2014-08-05,17.00,17.29,16.91,17.01,125500,16.67
    [14,1] = 2014-08-04
    [15,1] = ,
    [16,1] = 17.86
    [17,1] = ,
    [18,1] = 18.80
    [19,1] = ,
    [20,1] = 18.96
    [21,1] = ,
    [22,1] = 19.10
```

... and so on.

my goal is to have the data like this:

```
hist_data = 
    [ 
      2014-08-22    16.08    16.19    15.80    16.00    139800    16.00
      2014-08-21    16.16    16.33    16.00    16.10    128500    16.10
      ...
    ]
```

other tries i've done:

```
hist_data = textscan(hist_data_f, '%s,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d','Delimiter',',')
hist_data = csvread('hist_data.csv')
```

i cant seem to get the desired output.
any suggestions?

ive read through
[Reading CSV files with MATLAB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19613232/reading-csv-files-with-matlab)
[Reading .csv file into MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15174749/reading-csv-file-into-matlab)
and some others without luck.

Comment: Shouldn't you put the string item between quotations?

Comment: What do you mean by `hist_data = [ 2014-08-22 16.08 ...]`? Do you mean a cell array (in order to mix strings and numbers)?

Comment: yes @LuisMendo, sorry that it isnt too clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about: [csv read](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/csvread.html) for the numeric part

```
%reads the csv file from row 1 on, to avoid the headers, and string date
M = csvread('test.csv',1,1);
```

the out put is then as required:

```
 M =

   1.0e+05 *

    0.0002    0.0002    0.0002    0.0002    1.3980    0.0002
    0.0002    0.0002    0.0002    0.0002    1.2850    0.0002
    0.0002    0.0002    0.0002    0.0002    2.7120    0.0002
    0.0002    0.0002    0.0002    0.0002    3.7960    0.0002
    0.0002    0.0002    0.0002    0.0002    2.5920    0.0002
    0.0002    0.0002    0.0002    0.0002    1.9090    0.0002
```

Comment: this is a clean solution. i also splitted it finally but slightly different. thank you

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how are the `,` in the format specifier interpreted. I think you are looking for:

`textscan(str,'%s%d%d%d%d%d','Delimiter',',')`

Answer (score 0):

Sebastien - if all you want is a cell array of strings in your `hist_data` then why not continue as before, but just treat every line as if it were a string instead of trying to determine which are strings and which are numbers?  Something like

```
hist_data_f = fopen(hist_path)
fgets(hist_data_f);
hist_data = textscan(hist_data_f, '%s\n');  % now every line is a string only
```

`hist_data` is a cell array, and so now just replace all commas with four (or more) spaces

```
hist_data = strrep(hist_data{1},',','    ');

hist_data = 
    '2014-08-22    16.08    16.19    15.80    16.00    139800    16.00'
    '2014-08-21    16.16    16.33    16.00    16.10    128500    16.10'
    '2014-08-20    16.00    16.28    15.78    16.15    271200    16.15'
    '2014-08-19    16.20    16.27    15.96    16.04    379600    16.04'
    '2014-08-18    16.87    16.87    16.10    16.16    259200    16.16'
    '2014-08-15    16.54    16.55    16.21    16.38    190900    16.38'
```

Try the above and see what happens!